# WP7 HttpWebRequest check if file exists (synchronously)

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-7

I need to check if a file exists and I need to do it from several places in code.
Some of the places I can handle it with a callback (kinda ugly but it will work).  But the one I don't know how to handle seems to require that it be Synchronous.

I need to call the method to check if it exist from a RelayCommand as the "canExecute" method.
Any ideas on how to handle this?

This is what I currently have but calling the .WaitOne on the UI thread is blocking the background worker so it completely locks the app.

```
private bool FileExists(Uri file)  
    {  
        var exists = false;

        ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>{

            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(file);
            request.Method = "HEAD"; //only request the head so its quick

            request.BeginGetResponse(result =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //var response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
                    var req = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

                    exists = (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK");
                }
                catch
                {
                    exists = false;

                }
                resetEvent.Set();
            }
            , request);
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        resetEvent.WaitOne();

        return exists;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never make HTTPWebRequest's synchronous on the UI thread - this could block the UI for seconds or minutes...

If you really want to make an HTTPWebRequest appear to be synchronous on a background thread then simply use a ManualResetEvent inside a callback - e.g. something like:

```
var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent();
theHttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse((result) => {
       var response = theHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
       // use response.StatusCode to check for 404?
       resetEvent.Set();
    });
resetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Also, please note that checking if a file exists over HTTP might be better done by calling a small webservice which does the check - it depends on the size of the file you are checking.

Comment: I'm only requesting the header, and setting up a webservice to check for it seems overkill

Comment: I tried your code, but the UI thread is blocking the webrequest, and calling the WaitOne() is blocking the UI thread, so the app just locks up.

Comment: See my first sentence - "You should never make HTTPWebRequest's synchronous on the UI thread" - of course you are locking the UI thread if you call this block of code on the UI thread...

Comment: I saw that.  So how do I get it to not run on the UI thread.  I tried thread.Start() and QueWorkerItem.  But they all seem to have the same affect of being blocked by the UI.

Comment: You should be able to do this using the threading techniques you described. However, it feels like you're not grasping that what you are trying to do is always going to make the UI go slow. The UI thread needs to check the CanExecute value in order to update the UI - so you must return from CanExecute before the UI can continue. If you choose to synchronously wait for a network call inside CanExecute then you must expect the UI to not update while its waiting for your network call. Your only way to avoid this is to look at an asynchronous technique instead of looking for a synchronous solution

Comment: I'm not too worried about it being slow at the moment the canExecute is only called when the app first loads and when the user clicks a button on one page, and I'm only requesting the Head.    I put my current code above if you have any ideas about why the WaitOne() blocks the BackgroundWorker

Comment: My experience with WaitOne() on the phone is that it blocks the thread performing the work you are waiting for and therefore never releases. Find an async pattern like the one suggested by Denis.

Comment: WaitOne() is supposed to block the thread - "synchronous" means "blocking"!

Comment: Stuart, I'm fine with it blocking the thread, as long as its only the UI thread and not the background thread

Comment: Sorry - I've completely lost you... as a user I'm also never going to be happy if the UI "freezes" while you talk to the network - especially when I'm on a train in London - good luck with that network...

Comment: Just to be clear on this - if you are using HttpWebRequest, then HttpWebRequest does not by default use the UI thread for the handlers - e.g. http://www.rudigrobler.net/blog/wp7-webclient-vs-httpwebrequest or http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/216188.aspx

Comment: I read that somewhere too, that's why I don't understand why the WaitOne() is blocking the backgroundworker, and even without the backgroundworker it was still blocking the httpwebrequest.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible. You can never make synchronous calls to web services in Silverlight.

You have to leave *canExecute* method empty (to always execute the command), and make async call to check if file exists in handler for the command. The real code for the command has to execute in handler for that async call.

I think it is only way you can manage it.

btw-you can use lambda expressions to make it *look more like synchronous code*. Or maybe Reactive Extensions may help with *better looking code* ([jesse's tutorial](http://jesseliberty.com/reactive-extensions-rx/)).

Comment: I know that isn't synchronous, but I was hoping someone might know a trick with lambdas, manualresetevent or someway to wrap it and make it act synchronous.

Comment: @tyler "make it act synchronous" <-- this is just not possible. Take a look at Reactive Extensions, it makes your code **look more** synchronous, but it always be async - there are no tricks.

Comment: Robert,  I'm trying to check if a file exists for the "canExecute" parameter of RelayCommand.  I don't want to execute the command if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this problem is to create some kind of flag ( i.e IsFileExists) and return that flag from CanExecute method. Flag shold be set to false initially and your button disabled under assumption that untill we know that file does exits we consider it doesn't. Next I would fire HTTPWebRequest or wcf call or any other async method to check if file exists. Once callback confirms that file exists set flag to true and fire CanExecuteChanged event. If you want to be fancy you can add some visual feedback while waiting for responce. In general user experienc would be much better than locking up screen for duration of the web request.